# How to store server data inside my class property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, fetch-api

This is my first post, just to mention I'm naive to the StacKOverFlow manners.

I am a beginner to JavaScript and building a *HangMan* game by first making a generic HangMan class to be used by anyone; and then using it to set up my own game in a local web project. Below is my current progress with class (for reference):-

```
class HangMan {
    constructor() {
        this.wordLength = [4, 9];
        this.triesLeft = 10;
        this.triesInputted = this.triesLeft;
        this.allWords = HangMan.returnAllWords();
        this.chosenWord = HangMan.returnWord(this.allWords, this.wordLength);
    }


    static returnWord(words, range) {
        let allWords = words.then();
        let selectedWords = allWords.filter(function(word) {
            console.log(word, word.length);
            if (word.length >= range[0] && word.length <= range[1]) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        const word = selectedWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectedWords.length)];
        return word;
    }
    static async returnAllWords() {
        const fileResponse = await fetch('words.txt');
        const textResponse = await fileResponse.text();
        const words = textResponse.replaceAll('\r\n', ' ').split(' ');
        return words;
    }

    setTries(tries) {
        this.triesLeft = tries;
        this.triesInputted = tries;
    }
    setWordLength(lowerLimit, upperLimit) {
        this.wordLength[0] = lowerLimit;
        this.wordLength[1] = upperLimit;
        this.chosenWord = HangMan.returnWord(this.allWords, this.wordLength);
    }
}

let game = new HangMan();
game.setTries(12);
game.setWordLength(3, 8);
```

I want to store all the words from a text file in the class property **this.allWords** in the form of an array. I want to do this with a function **HangMan.returnAllWords()**, which I want to be inaccessible from outside and only called once at the loading of the webpage, so that I don't have to fetch it again at restart game, and can use this to randomize a word again. After much browsing, I realized I need to use *fetch() Promises* with *async / await* to fetch data from *words.txt* inside my root folder. But the async function **HangMan.returnAllWords()** turned to be another Promise. I need another another inaccessible function **HangMan.returnWord()** to randomize a word from the array of words. I wanna call this once at the loading of the page and whenever I restart my game. I am not able to send the **this.allWords** property as an argument inside the **HangMan.returnWord()** function. Even if I send it as a promise, it becomes pending inside the function and I can't make the constructor **async**.

I have a a beginner level of knowledge with synchroneity and proper class implementation. Please help me with this- how can I make this work? Or my software design is weak or what should I study and from where?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use promises in class constructor straightforward. So it's better to change program design and use functions. I.e. load words from file first, then pass this array as parameter while creating `New` object from your `Class`.

If you want to load file within class constructor logic, you can try hacks like wrapping constructor in self-exec function, like

```
class AsyncConstructor {
  constructor(value) {
    return (async () => {

      // Call async functions here
      
      this.value = value;
      return this;
    })();
  }
}
```

Also some additional info about async/await

If you call `async` function, you need `await` for it's result. Please, look at the quick example below and read inline comments. Then run this snippet and inspect the result.

```js
// Timeout function for our example
const timeout = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

// File loading async function
const myAsyncFunction = async () => {
  console.log(`I'm async function doing some loading stuff...`);
  
  // Wait 1 sec to imitate file loading, processing and etc
  await timeout(1000);
  
  // Return some result
  return ['one', 'two', 'three'];
}

// Now we want to call myAsyncFunction and get it's
// result, not promise. So we need to wait untill
// async function complete all it's stuff. If we
// want to use 'await', function has to be 'async'
const test1 = async () => {
  // Call myAsyncFunction and wait for result
  const result = await myAsyncFunction();
  
  // Print result
  console.log(result);
}

//
// Now we'll make same function, but without 'await'
const test2 = () => {
  // Call myAsyncFunction without await
  const result = myAsyncFunction();
  
  // Print result
  console.log(result);
}

//
// Run tests
(async () => {
  // Test 1
  console.log(`Running test1() with await`);
  await test1();
  
  // Let's make 1 sec pause
  console.log(`-----`);
  await timeout(1000);
  
  // Test 2
  console.log(`Running test2() WITHOUT await`);
  test2();
})();
```

As you can see, in `test1` we get proper result, but in `test2` we get `{}` instead of our array, because we do not wait for async result.

Comment: Can you be please more specific about how can I implement this in my class. I am unable to extract the Promise result to a class property inside my constructor function and when I try to do that inside another static function, the promise becomes pending.

Comment: You can't use promises in class constructor. Well, you can use hacks, but I think it's better to change your design and use regular functions instead of constructor.

Comment: Ok! How can I do that?

Comment: Well I mean it's better to do file loading stuff before creating `new` from class... Just load words from file, then pass this array while creating New object from class